# Simplifying $(x-1)\cdot(x-3)\cdots (x-(n-2))$ in terms of binomial coefficients.

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Can we write the following product in terms of binomial coefficients ?
$(x-1)\cdot(x-3)\cdots (x-(n-2))$.
i.e the the product take up odd numbers.

Comment: Using *only* binomial coefficients?  Why would you want to restrict yourself like that?  Using *any* simplification?  Yes, of course.  See [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).  Remember that you can "multiply by one" whenever you like and it doesn't change the values, and that a value divided by itself equals $1$... So you have for instance $(x-1)(x-3)(x-5)\cdots = \frac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)\cdots}{(x-2)(x-4)\cdots}$.

Comment: Are you assuming $n$ is odd? [otherwise last term doesn't match pattern]

Comment: As for your specific expression, it is unclear whether $x$ is even or odd.  It is unclear if $n$ is even or odd.  It is unclear whether you allow things like $2^k$ or factorials in your simplification, and so on...

Comment: Is there any notation for the product $(x-1)\cdot(x-3)\cdots(x-(n-2))$ over certain factorial ? (here $x$ is a complex number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting your question... you ask to simplify $\underbrace{(x-1)(x-3)(x-5)\cdots (x-(2k-1))}_{k~\text{terms in the product}}$ where $x$ is any complex number.

I reintroduce the notation for the *falling factorial* $z\frac{n}{~}=\underbrace{z(z-1)(z-2)\cdots(z-n+1)}_{n~\text{terms in the product}}$

I will assume that $x$ is not an integer from $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,k\}$ to avoid possible division by zero errors.  Following from the approach used for simplifying double factorials and using the more generic *falling factorials* rather than factorials, we have:

$(x-1)(x-3)(x-5)\cdots(x-(2k-1)) = \dfrac{x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\cdots(x-(2k-1))}{x(x-2)(x-4)\cdots (x-(2k-2))}$

$ = \dfrac{x\frac{2k}{~}}{x(x-2)(x-4)\cdots(x-(2k-2))} = \dfrac{x\frac{2k}{~}}{2^k(\frac{x}{2})(\frac{x}{2}-1)(\frac{x}{2}-2)\cdots(\frac{x}{2}-k+1)}$

$$=\dfrac{x\frac{2k}{~}}{2^k(\frac{x}{2})\frac{k}{~}}$$

In the case that $x$ was among the numbers $1,3,5,\dots,2k-1$ then the product is simply zero, and in the case that $x$ was among the numbers $0,2,4,6,\dots,2k-2$ then it is as above but having skipped the zero term from numerator and denominator.